# Where to find practical well-designed database schema examples to learn from?

Tags: database

I am new to database schema design and I want to learn more about how a well-designed database scheme is implemented in the real world?

Is there any places to find those schemes? Or is there any book focused on explanation over examples.

Comment: Never seen an off-topic get so many upvotes and so many starts

Comment: There's also https://dbschemalibrary.com/ (disclaimer: I developed this)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

[**DatabaseAnswers.org**](https://web.archive.org/web/20160308080311/http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/) <sub>(unfortunately [now defunct](http://www.databaseanswers.org/))</sub> [but well-preserved in the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160308080311/http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/) is a great source of example database schemas.

I can also recommend [Beginning Database Design](http://www.apress.com/9781590597699), published by Apress. I own this book and can confirm that it is of high quality. The book looks at a number of real world scenarios and explains the impact a certain design decision could have on the way the database works and the quality of the data and its output.

Finally I would advise building some small databases (E.G. contact management, Task list etc). Start by specifying some basic requirements and create some tables and queries. You WILL make some mistakes which is the best way of learning.

Comment: The first link gives me `Bad Request (Invalid Hostname)`.

Comment: It worked yesterday when I tested it. I have just tried following the link and now get the same result as you. The website is called Database Answers. Searching for this through Google gives the same result so there must be a temporary problem with the site.

Comment: I think it's a virus because the meta description (or rather the webmaster) of the site says that, too: `A while back Google and Bing told me there might be a virus in this Home Page. I got rid of it but I have cut this page down to a minimum as a precaution.`

Comment: It appears the problem is solved and the link I provided now works.

Comment: Do you recommend this [book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0128043997/ref=rdr_ext_tmb) compared to the one you recommended in your answer?

Comment: Still very helpful in 2020 for both beginner and anvanced database designers. Thank you for sharing useful websites like these ones. :)

Comment: https://fordnox.github.io/databaseanswers/data_models/index.htm

Answer (score 25):

Here is a nice library of schemas to browse through.
http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models