# Navigation Drawer Fragments Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-sqlite, navigation-drawer

I am making a TODO app. I have a navigation drawer which contains items like Work, Personal etc. When you click on Work it opens work Fragment in which you can add a Task. Similarly for Personal. In work and Personal `Fragment`, I am storing the TODO list in `SQLite` database. Do i need to create a separate table for each fragment?
Right now i am creating only 1 table and when i add a task it gets added to both Work and Personal.

TaskContract.java

```
public final class TaskContract {

    private TaskContract(){}

    public static final String CONTENT_AUTHORITY="com.example.android.tasks";
    public static final Uri BASE_CONTENT_URI=Uri.parse("content://"+CONTENT_AUTHORITY);
    public static final String PATH_TASKS="tasks";

    public static final class TaskEntry implements BaseColumns{
        public static final Uri CONTENT_URI=Uri.withAppendedPath(BASE_CONTENT_URI,PATH_TASKS);
        public static final String CONTENT_LIST_TYPE=
                ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE+"/"+CONTENT_AUTHORITY+"/"+PATH_TASKS;
        public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE=
                ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE+"/"+CONTENT_AUTHORITY+"/"+PATH_TASKS;
        public static final String TABLE_NAME="tasks";

        public static final String _ID=BaseColumns._ID;
        public static final String NAME="taskname";
        public static final String DUEDATE="duedate";
        public static final String DUETIME="duetime";
    }
}
```

TaskDBHelper.java

```
public class TaskDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="list.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;

    public TaskDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String SQL_CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME+
                " ("+TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                +TaskContract.TaskEntry.NAME+" TEXT NOT NULL, "
                +TaskContract.TaskEntry.DUEDATE+" TEXT, "
                +TaskContract.TaskEntry.DUETIME+" TEXT);";


        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

TaskProvider.java

```
public class TaskProvider extends ContentProvider {

    private static final String TAG = "TaskProvider";
    private static final int TASKS=100;
    private static final int TASK_ID=101;
    private static final UriMatcher URI_MATCHER=new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

    static {
        URI_MATCHER.addURI(TaskContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY,TaskContract.PATH_TASKS,TASKS);
        URI_MATCHER.addURI(TaskContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY,TaskContract.PATH_TASKS+"/#",TASK_ID);
    }

    private TaskDBHelper taskDBHelper;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {

        taskDBHelper=new TaskDBHelper(getContext());
        return true;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String[] projection, @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] selectionArgs, @Nullable String sortOrder) {
       SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=taskDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor;

        int match=URI_MATCHER.match(uri);
        switch (match){
            case TASKS:
                cursor=sqLiteDatabase.query(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME,projection,selection,
                        selectionArgs,null,null,sortOrder);
                break;
            case TASK_ID:
                selection= TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID+"=?";
                selectionArgs=new String[]{String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri))};
                cursor=sqLiteDatabase.query(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME,projection,selection,
                        selectionArgs,null,null,sortOrder);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot query Unknown Uri "+uri);
        }
        cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(),uri);
        return cursor;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getType(@NonNull Uri uri) {
        final int match = URI_MATCHER.match(uri);
        switch (match) {
            case TASKS:
                return TaskContract.TaskEntry.CONTENT_LIST_TYPE;
            case TASK_ID:
                return TaskContract.TaskEntry.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown URI " + uri + " with match " + match);
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Uri insert(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable ContentValues values) {
        final int match=URI_MATCHER.match(uri);
        switch (match){
            case TASKS:
                return insertTask(uri,values);
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insertion is not supported for "+uri);

        }
    }

    private Uri insertTask(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        String name=values.getAsString(TaskContract.TaskEntry.NAME);
        if(name==null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Task Name is required");
        }

       /* String duedate=values.getAsString(TaskContract.TaskEntry.DUEDATE);
        if(duedate==null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("DUEDATE is required");
        }

        String duetime=values.getAsString(TaskContract.TaskEntry.DUETIME);
        if(duetime==null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("DUETIME is required");
        }*/

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=taskDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        long id=sqLiteDatabase.insert(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                null,values);
        if(id==-1){
            return null;
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri,null);
        return ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri,id);
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] selectionArgs) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = taskDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        // Track the number of rows that were deleted
        int rowsDeleted;

        final int match = URI_MATCHER.match(uri);
        switch (match) {
            case TASKS:
                // Delete all rows that match the selection and selection args
                rowsDeleted = database.delete(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
                break;
            case TASK_ID:
                // Delete a single row given by the ID in the URI
                selection = TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID + "=?";
                selectionArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri)) };
                rowsDeleted = database.delete(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Deletion is not supported for " + uri);
        }

        // If 1 or more rows were deleted, then notify all listeners that the data at the
        // given URI has changed
        if (rowsDeleted != 0) {
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        }

        // Return the number of rows deleted
        return rowsDeleted;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable ContentValues values, @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] selectionArgs) {
        final int match=URI_MATCHER.match(uri);
        switch (match){
            case TASKS:
                return updateTask(uri,values,selection,selectionArgs);

            case TASK_ID:
                selection = TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID + "=?";
                selectionArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri)) };
                return updateTask(uri, values, selection, selectionArgs);
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Update is not supported for " + uri);

        }

    }

    private int updateTask(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        if (values.containsKey(TaskContract.TaskEntry.NAME)) {
            String name = values.getAsString(TaskContract.TaskEntry.NAME);
            if (name == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Task requires a name");
            }
        }

        if (values.containsKey(TaskContract.TaskEntry.DUEDATE)) {
            String duedate = values.getAsString(TaskContract.TaskEntry.DUEDATE);
            if (duedate == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Task requires a duedate");
            }
        }

        if (values.containsKey(TaskContract.TaskEntry.DUETIME)) {
            String duetime = values.getAsString(TaskContract.TaskEntry.DUETIME);
            if (duetime == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Task requires a duetime");
            }
        }


        // If there are no values to update, then don't try to update the database
        if (values.size() == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        // Otherwise, get writeable database to update the data
        SQLiteDatabase database = taskDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        // Perform the update on the database and get the number of rows affected
        int rowsUpdated = database.update(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);

        // If 1 or more rows were updated, then notify all listeners that the data at the
        // given URI has changed
        if (rowsUpdated != 0) {
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        }

        // Return the number of rows updated
        return rowsUpdated;

    }
}
```

This is my database and table creation code. Should i create these classes for each Fragment. Please help?
My app is similar to Google Keep app

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good way to create the table for each fragment. The database design should be independent of the views created for it. So, that you can use same tables to show different views based on the table fields.

I think you need database schema design to make a good database. You can refer this link - [Where to find practical well-designed database schema examples to learn from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993842/where-to-find-practical-well-designed-database-schema-examples-to-learn-from)

In context to your question, you would have one table as 'node', which will have the common columns of all the task types. Suppose, 'personal task' type includes reminder time not the same for the 'work' then, you create 'reminder' table that stores the 'node_id' along with 'time'. In this way, decide the tables and columns needed for the app.

You have to decide `database schema` on your app requirements.

Hope this helps.